# How to convert a URL object to a String

Tags: java

I would like to convert a URL to a String. I have searched online and cannot find anything that works. Apparently there is a toString(URL) method but I can't get that to work.

```
public String getLocationJar(){
    URL fileLocation = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();

    return toString(fileLocation);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't get that to work? What are your expectations, what are the actual results?

Comment: Why I didn't work? Post the code you have tried, so it's easier for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry, added. I've also tried it with URL.toString(fileLocation) but nothing.

Comment: [`return fileLocation.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#toString%28%29)

Comment: Works! Why doesn't it work when you put it inside the brackets though?

Comment: because it isn't a static method of the class URL or a method of your class.  In general, that is how you call toString() on anything, `Object.toString()`

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you just need to either call `fileLocation.toString()` or maybe `fileLocation.getPath()`. The following code:

```
URL fileLocation = Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();

System.out.println(fileLocation.toString());
System.out.println(fileLocation.getPath());
```

Outputs the desired Path:

```
file:/C:/Users/xxx/Dev/Workspace/proj/target/classes/
/C:/Users/xxx/Dev/Workspace/proj/target/classes/
```

So, just change your code to `return fileLocation.toString()`